# data copied from one shee to other does replacement instead of append

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I wish to know what is wrong in this piece of code. My objective is to copy data from sheet2 to sheet1. the code is working but the record that is getting copied to shee1 is replaced with data in row1, it does not append. I want the data to get copied underneath every row.

```
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    With ws
        Set rngsh1 = .UsedRange
    End With
    For Each cel1 In rngsh1
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
                Set rng = .Rows(1).Find(cel1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    cel1.Offset(, 1).Copy .Cells(rng.Row + 1, rng.Column)
                End If
            End With

    Next
```

Comment: I think you wanted some thing like this <https://www.dropbox.com/s/5makmzq38ahnt2f/data%20copy%20append.xlsx?dl=0> Also please update your code for benefit of others.

Answer (score 1):

This will append values from Sheet2 into new rows on Sheet1:

```
For Each cel1 In Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rng = .UsedRange.Rows(1).Find(cel1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Column) = cel1.Offset(, 1)
        End If

    End With

Next
```

but your initial code only searches Row 1 on Sheet1. I you want to search all values:

```
For Each cel1 In Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rng = .UsedRange.Find(cel1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Column) = cel1.Offset(, 1)
        End If

    End With

Next
```

Comment: Thanks. I achieved my task by changing the +1 in this line to a variable LastRow 'cel1.Offset(, 1).Copy .Cells(rng.Row + 1, rng.Column)' I also looked at both the options you suggested but the data is not copied in one line. For eg. it will copy in A1 then B2 then C3 and so on....